# React Suspense with Next.Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, radix-ui

React Suspense does not working with Next.JS(i used a skeleton from shadcn/ui as a fallback)

[when image is loading, there are no any skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d5Gk.png)
shadcn/ui is wrapper of radix ui

i tried to use to set position absoloute and z-10 to skeleton, but it does not help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide us with more information to handle your problem.
Based on my experience with suspense, probably your problems have caused by one of these.

- make sure data fetching placed under the suspense provider
- if you use swr or react-query turn on suspense option
- if css seems to be the problem, consider using create portal of React